# Set instance-initiated-shutdown-behaviour to terminate using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

How do I set instance initiated shutdown behaviour to terminate in boto3? It's not a parameter in launch specification.

Answer (score 2):

Value can be `stop` or `terminate`

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')
client.modify_instance_attribute(
   InstanceId='i-02e32c8a205c0788c',
   InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior={
        'Value': 'terminate'
    }
)
```

To set this during instance launch:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.create_instances(...
...
InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior='terminate',
...
)
```

See: [create_instances](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances)

Comment: I am making a spot_instance_request in which I want to specify InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehaviour. I get an error 'Invalid Parameter'

Comment: @user2851669 Because start/stop is not supported by spot instances. You need to know how to ask questions. There is no mention of spot instances in your question. Had I known that I wouldn't have spent my time answering in detail to your question.

Comment: You are right, should have mentioned that. I assumed that InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehaviour is supported in both spot and on demand.